# Windows MKLINK to a local directory

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging

In UNIX, an application can be installed on an NFS shared directory, and contain symlinks that point to /local (e.g. for logs and temp files). Each running instance of the application will then utilize local disk instead of the NFS.

In Windows, I have an application that uses a Windows shared directory (`\\shares\app`) for all instances of the app. The logs are in this directory (`\\shares\app\log`), but cannot be configured within the app to write locally. I've tried using MKLINK /D to create a link to `C:\logs\` (`\\shares\app\logs <==> C:\logs`), but this link cannot be used on remote instances of the app accessing the share.

Is there a way to do this in Windows, as is done with UNIX apps? My app's performance is degraded due to the amount of logs being written to the share, and it really should be written locally if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, links like that won't be allowed.  Even samba has symbolic links turned off by default [due to some security issues with the way they are handled in windows](http://www.samba.org/samba/news/symlink_attack.html).

Windows resolves links on the server side, so if it works at all, it would be pointing to c:\logs on the file server.

I'd suggest configuring where the app logs to (possibly requiring requesting that the vendor add such an option), so it can log locally.

Comment: We've requested that the application allow configuring of the logs directory. I'm not sure why it is designed this way. The app is QilkView... I didn't include this in the original question. We currently are reducing the logging to maximize performance and reduce I/O on the share.